# How to create an ID that increases based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, primary-key, data-cleaning

I need to create an ID that has increases by one according to some specific conditions:

1. RespondentID on row above was not the same as RespondentID on this row
2. When last row had Purpose == 1
3. When last row had Purpose == 7 AND TripNumber == 1

If more than one of these conditions apply, it still should only increase by 1.

```
data = {'RespondentID': [101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 106, 106, 106, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 110], 
        'TripNumber':   [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1], 
        'Purpose':      [4, 1, 6, 1, 7, 4, 1, 4, 6, 8, 6, 5, 1, 7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 6, 5, 1, 4]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

And I need to create

```
df['JourneyID'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
```

To break it down.

- 1: new (first) RespondentID.
- 2: last row had 1 in Purpose.
- 3, 5, 7, and 11: new RespondentID (and last row had 1 in Purpose).
- 4 and 10: last row had 7 in Purpose AND TripNumber was 1.
- 6 and 9: new RespondentID
- 8: new RespondentID (and last row had 7 in Purpose while TripNumber
  was 1)

**This solution worked well for condition 2:**

```
temp = ((df['purpose']==1).cumsum()+1).shift(1) 
#Makes it go up by one each time the previous row had purpose == 1
temp[0]=1
df['JourneyID'] = temp
```

but I also need it to increase by one with the other 2 conditions.

Comment: Please be clear about what is stopping you.  You know how to test a non-trivial condition -- you just need to write tests for your other rules, and join them with an `or` in your ID computation line.

Comment: I see what you mean. I didn't realise it was so simple to just add an "or".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a True/False Series that checks if **any** of those conditions are True. Then `cumsum` that Series. Using `.shift` allows us to check conditions on previous rows. The `.fillna(False)` fixes the first row when we `shift` as it gets `NaN`'d.

Because `df['RespondentID'].ne(df['RespondentID'].shift())` always returns True for the first row, the counting is gauranteed to start at 1

```
s = (
    df['RespondentID'].ne(df['RespondentID'].shift())                # Condition 1
    | df.Purpose.eq(1).shift().fillna(False)                         # Condition 2
    | (df.Purpose.eq(7) & df.TripNumber.eq(1)).shift().fillna(False) # Condition 3
    )

df['JourneyID'] = s.cumsum()
```